The question author in the Staging Ground can be affected by the reviewer lock, disallowing editing from them
When an SG item is in front of a reviewer, it applies an "In Review" lock to it, disallowing other reviewers from taking action on it, including editing. This is a good thing, as it tries to ensure two people don't bully over one another when reviewing a particular SG item.
However, based on a comment in this SG review, it looks like the author of a question in the SG can be affected by this review lock, preventing them from editing it. It looks like the question author was able to get an edit through and request re-evaluation in this case, but the comment that they received a notification that editing was locked indicates that they were, at some point, prevented from editing.
This really shouldn't be the case. The author should always be able to edit their own question, especially if that question is in a state other than New or Re-evaluate. I can't imagine this is intentional, so I've tagged this as a bug.

at the very least, getting more info about why a post is locked would be helpful. Ex. "this post is locked by  because they are editing it right now. here's their chat profile so you can message them if you want" (just spitballing. also, I don't know if that's how locks actually work :P).

@starball Pretty sure all it takes for a review lock to be applied is having an SG reviewer open it up. It's pretty loose about holding onto a lock when a reviewer closes the tab, leaves, skips, or takes a review action though (from my experience in the beta, this did take some finagling to get right, see this chat message in the beta chatroom from a developer for more details).

I think that during the beta, authors were able to pretty much block reviewer actions by opening the edit menu and I think they were even able to do that while a reviewer was looking at the post (i.e. it was possible that a reviewer was stopped from submitting a review action by the author performing an edit).

We spent some time looking into this and will mark as status-norepro
From the developer who investigated:

If a reviewer edits a Staging Ground post while the author has the edit page open they will see this message



This is how the system resolves conflicting edits, but it doesn’t stop the author from either refreshing the page and getting the newest version, or simply trying for a better edit as the message said.
If the author’s edit goes in first, this is what the reviewer sees


Additionally, when re-reviewing the SG question you linked, the author commented a few hours after you created this post on MSO saying that they were able to make changes.
